# Use HttpResponse with JSON data in this code

Tags: json, django

This code seems to work fine when I used Django console and just print it.

```
reference = FloodHazard.objects.filter(hazard='High')
ids = reference.values_list('id', flat=True)

for myid in ids:
    getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
    response = BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom).values(
        'brgy_locat').annotate(counthigh=Count('brgy_locat'))
    print response
```

I was able to show all the values, but when using HttpResponse, it returns an empty set. What is the proper way of returning JSON data from a queryset? So far, tried this:

```
reference = FloodHazard.objects.filter(hazard='High')
ids = reference.values_list('id', flat=True)
response = {}
for myid in ids:
    getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
    response['high'] = BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom).values(
        'brgy_locat').annotate(counthigh=Count('brgy_locat'))

json_post = ujson.dumps(list(response))
return HttpResponse(json_post, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no much sense in your code.  You assign all querysets to the single key in the `response` dict.  You should use a list for this purpose:

As far as I understand the code should be something like this:

```
response = []
for myid in ids:
    getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
    response.extend(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom)
                                     .values('brgy_locat')
                                     .annotate(counthigh=Count('brgy_locat')))

json_post = ujson.dumps(response)
```

If you want to return a hazard level as well as the list of buildings then you can return a dict:

```
json_post = ujson.dumps({'hazard': 'high', 'buildings': response})
```